# How to ignore th with specific class name in tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I use the tablesorter to sort the table, but not all columns, I want to ignore the specific column with the defined class name, eg:

```
<table class="basicList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th class="ck_field"><input type="checkbox" id="check_all" name="check_all" /></th>
                            <th class="col_filter"><a href="#" class="btn_filter">&nbsp;</a></th>
                            <th>Name <span class="sort_indicator">&nbsp;</span></th> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr class="filter_row"> 
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="the_name" name="name" class="filter_field"/></td> 
                        </tr>  
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

In this example, I don't want to sort the first two columns.

And I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log($(".basicList .col_filter").index());
    console.log($(".basicList .ck_field").index());

    var ck_ignore = $(".basicList .ck_field").index();
    var filter_ignore = $(".basicList .col_filter").index();

    $(".basicList").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'],headers: { 
            //disable the first checkbox cell            
            $ck_ignore: {                
                sorter: false 
            },
            $filter_ignore : {                
                sorter: false 
            }
        }  
    });
```

Which doesn't work, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have `$` in front of your variable names ?

Comment: @Khez: typically used to indicate they're jQuery objects, although in this case, it looks like they're used as dictionary keys....which is weird.

Comment: @Mark, I know what $ denotes, but he just created the 2 vars in question and they don't have `$`.

Comment: @Khez: ahh...but regardless, you can't use variables in objects keys when defined like that...? you have to do object[key] if you want the variable to be interpreted

Comment: I have a fork of tablesorter that allows you to set the column parser, or disable a column, using class names like `sorter-false` and `sorter-currency` - check out a [demo here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
var myHeaders = {};
myHeaders[ck_ignore] = { sorter: false };
myHeaders[filter_ignore] = { sorter: false };

$(".basicList").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], headers: myHeaders });
```

Note: if you have more columns with these classes, it will work only for the first occurences.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html), you can now use `class="sorter-false"`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, and here's what I came up with.  Assuming your `th` class for not sorting is called `nosort`:

```
function setupTablesorter() {
    $('table.tablesorter').each(function (i, e) {
        var myHeaders = {}
        $(this).find('th.nosort').each(function (i, e) {
            myHeaders[$(this).index()] = { sorter: false };
        });

        $(this).tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], headers: myHeaders });
    });    
}
```

This has a few advantages over the other answers I saw here.  First, it works even if you have multiple non-sortable columns.  Second, it also still works if you have multiple tables on the same page, each with different sortable columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the headers argument:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log($(".basicList .col_filter").index());
    console.log($(".basicList .ck_field").index());

    var ck_ignore = $(".basicList .ck_field").index();
    var filter_ignore = $(".basicList .col_filter").index();

    $(".basicList").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'],headers: {       
             // pass the headers argument and assing a object
        headers: {
            // assign the first column (we start counting zero)
            0: {
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }
        }
        ,
            $filter_ignore : {                
                sorter: false
            }
        }  
    });
```