# jQuery Tablesorter don't sort columns if has class

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I currently use the following to tell my table to not sort certain columns using the jquery Tablesorter plugin:

```
$(".uiGridContent table").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[1, 0]],
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false },
            5: { sorter: false },
            6: { sorter: false }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that on my app the user can add and remove columns so therefore the order can change so my current code is not a viable solution. If I put a class on the columns I DO not want to sort e.g. `<col class="nosort" />` how could I make it so it does not sort those columns?

Because I'm using `<col />` I have tried the following:

```
$filter_ignore = $("col.nosort").closest("th").index();

    $(".uiGridContent table").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[1, 0]],
        headers: {
            $filter_ignore: {
                sorter: false
            }
        }
    });
```

But doesn't work :/

I think I need some sort of loop to find all the th's with a column for them with the clase! Here is an example of my table:

```
<table>
 <colgroup>
  <col class="nosort" />
  <col />
 </colgroup>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">a</th>
    <th scope="col">b</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td scope="col">a</td>
    <td scope="col">b</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672993/how-to-ignore-th-with-specific-class-name-in-tablesorter

Comment: Hi, tried that (see OP) but doesn't work :/

Answer (score 11):

```
function setupTablesorter() {
    $('table.tablesorter').each(function (i, e) {
        var myHeaders = {}
        $(this).find('th.nosort').each(function (i, e) {
            myHeaders[$(this).index()] = { sorter: false };
        });

        $(this).tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], headers: myHeaders });
    });    
}
```

This seems to work best!

Answer (score 2):

I actually have a fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) that allows you to add `sorter-false` class to the table header to prevent sorting. You can also set the parser using this method (e.g. `sorter-currency`, etc). Here is [the demo that uses class names](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html), you can now use `class="sorter-false"`

Comment: Note this is for Mottie's (vastly superior) tablesorter fork.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `<col class="nosort" />` wont add that class to cols in its scope and I dont know how to get all colls under a colgroup or if its even possible. However if you would add class to the th, then its easy to get disable sorting on it.

```
var $filter_ignore = {};

$("th.nosort").each(function(i) {
    $filter_ignore[i] = {sorter: false};
});

$("table").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[1, 0]],
    headers: $filter_ignore
});
```

With this markup

```
<table>
 <colgroup>
  <col class="nosort" />
  <col />
 </colgroup>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col" class="nosort">a</th>
    <th scope="col">b</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td scope="col">a</td>
    <td scope="col">b</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That causes an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined`